# How does Redux Toolkit determine property names on the state object?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const countersSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'based? based on what',
    initialState: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    reducers: {
        updateCounter: (state, action) => {
            var id = action.payload.id
            var value = action.payload.value

            state[id] += value
        }
    }
})

export const { updateCounter } = countersSlice.actions

export const selectCount = id => state => state.counter[id]

export default countersSlice.reducer
```

Why is it that, in the `selectCount` line, I have to use `state.counter` when `.counter` isn't referenced anywhere else in the slice? I do like that it's `.counter` but I just want to understand how it's coming up with that property.

Comment: You should try to explain what does that code is supossed to do before anyone can try to help you.

Trying to guess what is supossed to do that code, you're right, `selectCount` is doing nothing. You should store a field like `chosenCounter`, and save on it the id of the counter you want to update.

However, like I've mentioned before, you should tell what you're trying to implement and then people will be able to help you.

Comment: But it does appear to be doing something, I'm importing it into other files which use it in for a p tag (just a small dumb test project while I'm learning)
https://hastebin.com/umadogatud.js
If I change .counter to something else, it breaks the entire project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `name` property in `createSlice` is used internally by redux-toolkit to create the names for your actions.  If the name is `'counter'` then the `updateCounter` action will have `{ type: 'counter/updateCounter' }`.  If it's `'abc'` then your action will have `{ type: 'abc/updateCounter' }`.  **This name doesn't matter**.  As long as it's different from any other reducers in your app then you're fine.

> If I change .counter to something else, it breaks the entire project

Now you are talking about something else, which is how you select your data from the root state of your app.

```
export const selectCount = id => state => state.counter[id]
```

This selector function assumes that the reducer from this slice will be on the `counter` property of your root reducer.  The location of this reducer relative to the root state is **determined by the property key** when you combine your reducers with `configureStore` or `combineReducers`.

Your current selector assumes that your store looks like this:

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import counterReducer from './yourReducerFile.js'

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer
  }
});
```

This property key often matches the `name` of your slice, but **it doesn't *have* to match**.

You can use any property key as long as the selector function uses the same one. For example:

```
export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    someOtherProperty: counterReducer
  }
});
```

```
export const selectCount = id => state => state.someOtherProperty[id]
```